# adding items to array during emit overrides the previous element in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working on a project , where i have a use case to add a new list item on click of add button and the added data must be rendered as a new list item.

> add content component

```js
import { Component,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'add-content',
  template:`<input type='text' [(ngModel)] = 'content'/>
            <button (click) = 'addNewContent(content)'>`
})
export class AddContentComponent {
  @Output() newContent: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();
  content: any;
  constructor() {
    this.content = {};
  }
  addNewContent(content) {
    if (content) {
      this.content.body = content;
      this.newContent.emit(this.content);
    }
  }
}
```

> contentlistcomponent

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector:'content-list',
   template:`<ul>
              <li *ngFor="let content of contentList">{{content.body}}</li>
              <add-content (newContent)=getContent($event)></add-content>
              </ul>`
   
});
export class ContentListComponent {
contentList:Array<any>;
constructor(){
 this.contentList = [];
}
getContent(content){
if(content){
  this.contentList.push(content);
}
}
```

when first content is added the list renders the typed content correctly however when second content is added the previous content is also replaced by the new content and two list items with last item's content is displayed.As I am newbie , I couldn't figure out where I am going wrong.Could anyone help me with this issue?

**EDIT**
I have created a plunker showing the issue,

https://plnkr.co/edit/Wgj4I9yAQjSxi1C91vnb?p=preview

Comment: can you throw this into a plunkr illustrating the offending behavior

Comment: @joshuaOhana I have created the plunker showing the issue

Comment: I got the same issue, did you resolved it ? could you show me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that object reference is maintained for **content** variable in **getContent** function. You need to do following to push to **contentList** without maintaining reference of previous values.

```
getContent(content){
 if(content){
  var copy = Object.assign({}, content);
  this.contentList.push(copy);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps !!